# When is a buffer solution considered efficient?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, ph, buffer

By this I mean what is the rigorous definition of a buffer solution?

I know that a buffer is a solution able to resist changes of $\mathrm{pH}$, but how much *resistance to $\mathrm{pH}$* does a solution need to be considered a buffer?

For example I was told that one cannot make an acetic acid buffer $\left(K_\mathrm{a} = 1.8 \times 10^{-5}\right)$ at a desired $\mathrm{pH}$ of 6.5. Is this true?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_solution#Buffer_capacity

Comment: @Blade: See how I manipulate $K_\mathrm{a}$ using ``$K_\mathrm{a}$`` formatting. Rate constants and equilibrium constants should be itallics such as other variables (*e.g.,* $V, T, R, P, x, y, z,$ etc.).

Comment: Who "told you", instead of teaching you how buffers work?

Comment: Buffer solution Is considered efficient, if it meets your criteria for pH stabilization. Note the buffers are defined qualitatively, not quantitatively. 1 M acetic acid buffer at pH 6.5 is roughly comparable in buffer capacity to 0.01 M acetic acid buffer at ideal pH 4.75. So it is inefficient buffer, but still a buffer.

Comment: Well, I´m not blaming you, but he seems to have left out a few important points in his teaching. A buffer is obviously most efficient when it is not too dilute *and* has not already used up part of its buffer capacity in one direction, i.e. it´s fresh. A fresh buffer solution is an equimolar mixture of an acid and its conjugate base. That means you have no choice in the pH. It´s a property of the compound pair.

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency of a buffer is not an absolute parameter, but it is conditional and case dependent.

If buffer differencial capacity ( $\frac{\mathrm{d}n}{\mathrm{dpH}}\cdot \frac{1}{V}$, where $n$ is molar amount of an added base/acid and $V$ is buffer volume)
or integral capacity ($\frac{\Delta n}{\Delta \mathrm{pH}}\cdot \frac{1}{V}$ per $\Delta pH = \pm 1$) meet criteria required by the solution of interest, the buffer is efficient and vice versa. The same buffer may be efficient for one application, while not for another.

As $\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log \frac{\ce{[A-]}}{c-\ce{[A-]}}=\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log {\ce{[A-]}} - \log{(c-\ce{[A-]})}$

then relative differential capacity wrt the maximal capacity at $\mathrm{pH}=\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ is $\frac{4}{ \frac{c}{\ce{[A-]}} + \frac{c}{c-\ce{[A-]}}} $, where $c$ is the total molar concentration of the buffer conjugate acid + base pair.